# Residue of $fg$ at $z_0$ equals $g(z_0)$ times residue of $f$ at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Let $g$ be a holomorphic function on a disk $\mathbb{D}(z_0, r)$ centered at $z_0$ of radius $r>0$. Suppose $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$. Show that $Res(fg, z_0)=g(z_0)Res(f, z_0)$.

Proof:

Since $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, we can represent it as
$$ g(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty d_n(z-z_0)$$ where $d_n=\frac{g^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$. Since $f$ has a pole at $z_0$, it is holomorphic on some annulus $\mathbb{A}(r_1, r_2, z_0)$ centered at $z_0$ with $r>r_2>r_1>0$. We can represent $f$ as follows:

$$ f(z) = \frac{h(z)}{z-z_0} = \sum\limits_{n=-1}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$$

where $h(z)$ is a function holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}(z_0, r_2)$ such that $h(z_0)\ne 0$.

Now, $fg(z)=\frac{d_0c_{-1}}{z-z_0}+O(1)$, so that $Res(fg,z_0)=d_0 c_{-1}$.

Also, $g(z_0)Res(f,z_0)=d_0c_{-1}$.

Hence, $Res(fg, z_0)=g(z_0)Res(f, z_0)$.

Do you think my proof is completely correct? I would appreciate your opinion.

Comment: This is one of the equivalent definition of the residue, yes, the coef of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ in the Laurent series

Comment: Everything looks fine.

Comment: I would have said "as $f$ has a SIMPLE pole .." but that may be a bit picky.